# Shortcut for object.attr == x in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In ruby I can use the following short cut to map object attributes:

```
objects.map(&:attribute)
```

is the same as:

```
objects.map { |object| object.attribute }
```

is there a similar shortcut for this, where I find the first object where attribute equals `x`?

```
def find_first_with_matching_attribute(x)
  objects.detect { |object| object.attribute == x }
end
```

Comment: I posted an answer before reading through your question carefully (I didn't notice that you want to compare `object.attribute` at first). The answer is: No, there's not similar syntax in your case.

Comment: well...it's a shame, but what can be done. thanks for your input!

Comment: Is it a specific attribute you have in mind or you'll set the attribute you want to match against as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shortcut

```
objects.map(&:attribute)
```

works because `&` calls `to_proc` on its argument and `Symbol#to_proc` looks something like this:

```
def to_proc
  proc { |x| x.send(self) }
end
```

so it's equivalent to

```
objects.map(&proc { |x| x.send(:attribute) }) # which is the same as
objects.map { |x| x.attribute }
```

So if you want to simplify the following code

```
objects.detect { |object| object.attribute == x }
```

You need some kind of object where `to_proc` would give you

```
proc { |x| x.send(attr) == val }
```

Unfortunately there is no such `to_proc` method built into Ruby, but you are free to define your own as daremkd points out.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way by defining to_proc in Array, check this out:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

class Array
  def to_proc
    proc { |receiver| receiver.send(self[0]) == self[1] }
  end
end

p a.detect(&[:capitalize, 'B']) #=> 'b'
```

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood what I was asking - although it seems like there is no shortcut according to Marek Lipka

Comment: I think the OP is looking for an attribute (or method) with a specific value, e.g. find the first object in `['a', 'bb', 'ccc']` with `object.length == 2`